# obtener elemento HTML al que hago click, pero no sus hijos

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hola me encuentro con el siguiente problema, creo en evento que me restorne el mismo elemento por consola. Pero si hago click en un hijo me retorna el hijo y no el elemento que asigne el evento en un incio. Como puedo evitar este comportamiento. Otra cosa a aclarar es que no puedo usar una funcion flecha dentro del addEventListener, pues luego debo remover el evento.

```js
const element= document.querySelectorAll("p")[0];

function test(e){
console.log(e.target)
}

element.addEventListener("click",test)
document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click",()=>{
  element.removeEventListener("click",test)
})
```

```html
<p>Esto es un <u>Text</u></p>
<button id="remove">Remover Evento</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes cambiar esto:

```javascript
console.log(e.target)
```

por esto:

```javascript
console.log(e.currentTarget)
```

Tal como explica su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

Event.currentTarget

> Identifica el target (objetivo) actual del evento, ya que el evento
> atraviesa el DOM. Siempre hace referencia al elmento al cual el
> controlador del evento fue asociado, a diferencia de event.target, que
> identifica el elemento el el que se produjo el evento.

En cuanto a las funciones flecha, si no te funciona pues lo pones como `function()` y te funcionará. Las funciones flecha tienen [algunas limitaciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Aún así, en tu snippet te está funcionando, no creo que sea problema.

```js
const element= document.querySelectorAll("p")[0];

function test(e){
console.log(e.currentTarget)
}

element.addEventListener("click",test)
document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click",function(){
  element.removeEventListener("click",test)
})
```

```html
<p>Esto es un <u>Text</u></p>
<button id="remove">Remover Evento</button>
```